# Rails: Stripe creating 2 x charges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have an Enrollment model. New enrollments are created when I receive Stripe charges.

For some reason my controller is creating 2 x Stripe charges and 2 x enrollment records each time I make a Stripe charge. Here's my Enrollment#create action:

```
def create
    # Amount in cents
    amount = params[:stripeAmount].to_i * 100

    # Create the customer in Stripe
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Create the charge using the customer data returned by Stripe API
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: amount,
      description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
      currency: 'usd'
    )

   if charge["paid"] == true
    @workshop = params[:workshop]
     @enrollment = Enrollment.new(user_id: current_user.id, workshop_id: @workshop)

     if @enrollment.save
        redirect_to thank_you_path + "?workshop=" + @workshop
     else
        flash[:notice] = "Please try again"
     end
   end

    # place more code upon successfully creating the charge
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
    flash[:notice] = "Please try again"
  end
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I've placed a bunch of puts in the code to help debug. The second charge is getting created right after I go "if @enrollment.save"

Comment: Data layer is Model domain, try to move the code responsible for payment into a model

Comment: I followed the Stripe guide here which is copy/paste what I've done: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails

Comment: How do you know, exactly, that it happens "right after Enrollment.save"? Also, do you have any callbacks (before_save, after_save or else) in your Enrollment?

Comment: @EugZol I created a new post over here with more thorough code. Basically I added a bunch of puts statements to help debug, and immediately after Enrollment.save, the form submits again.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129979/rails-stripe-form-being-posted-twice

Comment: Callbacks - just an after_save notification_mailer which gets sent out

Comment: I figured it out, posted in the other question. Basically just had the javascript which submits the form loaded twice..