# Stripe Creating Two Subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I just converted a functional model from using Stripe to create a `charge` to creating a `subscription` and for some reason now it is creating two subscriptions instead of one.  The code on my `new` view hasn't changed since it worked, so the problem isn't here (in my opinion), but since [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129979/rails-stripe-form-being-posted-twice) had a problem with the js I wanted to show it anyway:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $7.99/month</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Generator Subscription"
          data-amount="799"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Here's my controller, where I believe the problem must lie:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    unless current_user
      flash[:error] = "Step one is to create an account!"
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end

    if current_user.access_generator 
      flash[:notice] = "Silly rabbit, you already have access to the generator!"
      redirect_to controller: 'generators', action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def create
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken],
      :plan => "generator_access"
    )

    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(
      :customer => customer.id,
      :plan => "generator_access"
    )

    if subscription
      current_user.update_attributes(access_generator: true)
      current_user.update_attributes(stripe_customer_id: subscription.customer)
      current_user.update_attributes(stripe_sub_id_generator: subscription.id)
      flash[:notice] = "You have been granted almighty powers of workout generation! Go forth and sweat!"
      redirect_to controller: 'generators', action: 'new'
    end

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  def cancel_subscription
    @user = current_user
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_id)
    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(@user.stripe_sub_id_generator)

    if customer.cancel_subscription(params[:customer_id])
      @user.update_attributes(stripe_customer_id: nil, access_generator: false, stripe_sub_id_generator: nil)
      flash[:notice] = "Your subscription has been cancelled."
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error canceling your subscription. Please notify us."
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
  end

end
```

The `cancel_subscription` method works perfectly (once I manually delete the duplicate subscription via the stripe dashboard), so it really has to be something in the 'create' method.  I also checked my console and the information for the `User` attributes is being correctly updated to match the second of the two duplicate subscriptions being created.

Can anyone see why this code is yielding two subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Customer with a plan, corresponding subscription is created automatically. You don't need to create it manually.

Comment: Excellent!  That fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: This does not work in Stripe V3 and you need to explicitly create subscription using stripe customer id, i have added an answer too.

Comment: This does not work in Stripe V3 and you need to explicitly create subscription using stripe customer id, i have added an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

For Stripe V3, This is how you can create and check subscription to avoid multiple values for same customer - in below code, i create a trial subscription for a customer.

```
   ## method to create/fetch customer
   def create_or_retrieve_customer(user)
    customer = retrieve_stripe_customer(user)

    if customer.nil? or customer.deleted?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
        email: user.email,
        description: "Created on #{Time.zone.now.to_date}",
        name: user.username,
      })
    end
    customer
  end

   ## get the customer  
   customer = create_or_retrieve_customer(self)
    ##setup the subscription
    @subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      items: [
        {
          price: "prod_aksfdklajfl",
        },
      ],
      trial_end: 30.days.from_now.to_date.to_time.to_i,
      cancel_at_period_end: true,
      billing_cycle_anchor: 30.days.from_now.to_date.to_time.to_i
    })
```

Once you have the subscription id, store it in the DB in the user table, maybe and then validate it whenever neeeded.